# Calling a 3rd layer subclass using a 1st layer pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, abstract-class, multiple-inheritance, dynamic-arrays

I made a class hierarchy where the 1st layer super class is staff. In my 2nd layer I have 2 subclasses called admin staff and academic staff. (These two layers are also abstract classes). Academic staff have 2 more subclasses teaching only and research only.

In my main, am trying to create an array of 10 staff pointers(5 of admin and 5 of academic) and manipulate 3rd layer subclasses using the pointers.
Bare in mind the 3rd layer subclasses have behaviors which are not present in the in 1st or 2nd layer. Hence, I have to use type casting.
I can change my 3rd layer behavior individually like eg,

```
((ResearchStaff *)ptr[i])->setResearchHour(23);
```

but it gets very messy very quickly.
My question, how can i access my 3rd layer behaviors in a for or while loop without having to individually set them. Heres the main that im working with. Thanks A LOT!!

```
int main()
{
  Staff *ptr[10];
  for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
  {
    ptr[i] = new AdminStaff;
    ((AdminStaff *)ptr[i])->setAdmin(12);

    i++;
    ptr[i] = new TeachingStaff;
    (( TeachingStaff*)ptr[i])->setTeaching(16);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [Visitor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) pattern.

Add a method to your `Staff` class called `accept`, like this:

```
class Staff 
{
   //Other staff stuff
   public:
      void accept(const Visitor& v) = 0;
}
```

Add implementations to your leaf classes...

```
class ResearchTeacher
{
    //Other research teacher stuff...

    public:
       void accept(const Visitor& v) {
       v.visit(*this);
    }
}
```

Then define a Visitor that knows what to do with each type:

```
class Visitor
{
   public:
      void visit(ResearchTeacher& teacher) 
      {
         teacher.setResearch(16);
      }

      void visit(TeachingTeacher& teacher)
      {
         teacher.setTeaching(16);
      }

      void visit(AdminStaff& admin) 
      {
         admin.setAdmin(12);
      }
}
```

Now the calling code doesn't have to worry about it:

```
int main()
{
  Visitor v;
  Staff *ptr[10];
  for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
  {
    ptr[i] = new AdminStaff;
    ptr[i]->accept(v);

    i++;
    ptr[i] = new TeachingStaff;
    ptr[i]->accept(v);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things!

1. When you create a new derived class object, in this case `AdminStaff` or `TeachingStaff`, you don't have to typecast back to base to invoke a derived class method.

So instead of,

```
    ptr[i] = new TeachingStaff;
    (( TeachingStaff*)ptr[i])->setTeaching(16);
```

you can write something like,

```
    TeachingStaff *ts = ptr[i] = new TeachingStaff;
    ts->setTeaching(16);
```

2. You should only call the base class reference/ pointer to invoke methods which are common to all the classes.

Finally, if these classes do not have many attributes in common you can consider [composition](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/102-composition/) as an alternate design strategy instead of using multiple inheritance.